# Getting tables name in Console application

Tags: c#, console-application, sqlclient

I'm trying getting tables name in database, the connection is successful but the select Query give me (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand) in the result. below my code.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select TABLE_NAME from DBNAME.TABLES");
Console.WriteLine(cmd);
string SelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM dbo.DBNAME";
SqlCommand a = new SqlCommand(SelectQuery);
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

attach the output.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you must specify connection string

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select TABLE_NAME from DBNAME.TABLES", connection_string);
```

then you must execute the command->

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: the output terminated while I'm putting (Console.ReadLine();) does not show tables name

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to print the full qualified name of the `SqlCommand` class using `Console.WriteLine(a);`. When you attempting to print object of any class will result in printing full qualified name of the class you referred.

You have to fill the result for `SqlCommand` into `DataTable` using `SqlDataAdapter` as below:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select TABLE_NAME from DBNAME.TABLES", con);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dtTables = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dtTables);
for (int i = 0; i <= dtTables.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dtTables.Rows[i][0]);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do Console.WriteLine(a) it will print out the class name, its not running the SqlCommand query. You need to execute and store the data. Then you can print out the tables_name

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = a.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: the output terminated while I'm putting (Console.ReadLine();) does not show tables name